# How does VAO keep buffer bindings?

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer

I am struggling to understand how exactly VAO is handling buffer mapping.
What I'm doing could be described in this pseudocode:

```
SetUp:
  BindVAO
  BindArrayBuffer
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ExpectedMaxCount, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);//Allocate storage
  glEnableVertexAttribArray
  glVertexAttribPointer

  BindElementBuffer
  Allocate storage (no data yet)

  UnbindVAO
  UnbindArrayBuffer
  UnbindElementBuffer

Draw:
  SubArrayAndElementDataIfNeeded
  BindVAO
  DrawElements
```

1. Is this correct that when DrawElements is called OpenGL uses bound VAO to resolve array and element buffer bindings? After a Draw call the bound array buffer is 0, but element buffer is still the one that was used to Draw.
2. Is it mandatory to allocate buffer memory during VAO setup? Would VAO be invalidated if BufferData was called after setup?

Comment: There is no such thing as "setup" in OpenGL.  You define when to setup yourself, though you must bind the VAO back.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer: well, conceptually you are setting up a VAO, so why not putting it into a separate function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I am struggling to understand how exactly VAO is handling buffer mapping.

Be very careful when using the word "mapping" around "buffers"; that has [a specific meaning when dealing with buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping), one that you probably don't intend.

> Is this correct that when DrawElements is called OpenGL uses bound VAO to resolve array and element buffer bindings? After a Draw call the bound array buffer is 0, but element buffer is still the one that was used to Draw.

One has nothing to do with the other. A [Vertex Array Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), as the name implies, contains *all* of the state that is necessary to pull vertex data from arrays. When you bind one, all of that state comes back into the context.

The reason the "bound array buffer" is 0 after the call is because it was 0 *before* the call. Draw calls do not change OpenGL state.

Furthermore, you seem to have fallen for the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` trap. The `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding only matters to three functions: [`glVertexAttribPointer`, `glVertexAttribIPointer`, and `glVertexAttribLPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer) (see a pattern?). These are the *only* functions that look at that binding. What they do is take the buffer that is bound *at the time these functions are called* and associates that buffer with the current VAO. `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is *not* part of the VAO's state. A buffer object becomes associated with a VAO *only* when you call one of those three functions. Once you make that call, you can bind whatever you want to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` ***is*** part of the VAO's state.

> Is it mandatory to allocate buffer memory during VAO setup? Would VAO be invalidated if BufferData was called after setup?

Technically no, but it's good form to not use a buffer until it has storage. Especially if they're static buffers.

Comment: And when that VAO's buffer association, set by `glVertexAttrib*Pointer`, gets broken? After unbinding VAO? Or just binding to another array buffer?

Comment: @id256: I'm not sure what your question means. The associations get "broken" only by subsequent calls to `glVertexAttrib*Pointer`. The whole point of a VAO is that it *preserves* this state, that this state is set within the VAO. So it only loses it when you deliberately and explicitly change it.

Comment: Yes, I obviously should have double-quoted "broken". Thanks for the explanation.